# C++ OpenCV: What is the easiest way to apply 2-D convolution

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++

I have a Kernel filter that I generated and I want to apply it to my image but I could not get a right result by doing this:
Actually I can use a different method as well since I am not to familiar with opencv I need help thanks.

channel[c] is the read image;

```
int size = 5; // Gaussian filter box side size
double gauss[5][5];

int sidestp = (size - 1) / 2;
```

// I have a function to generate the gaussiankernel filter

```
float sum = 0;
for (int x = 1; x < channels[c].cols - 1; x++){
    for (int y = 1; y < channels[c].rows - 1; y++){
        for (int i = -size; i <= size; i++){
            for (int j = -sidestp; j <= sidestp; j++){
                sum = sum + gauss[i + sidestp][j + sidestp] * channels[c].at<uchar>(x - i, y - j);
            }
        }
        result.at<uchar>(y, x) = sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV has an inbuilt function [filter2D](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=filter2d#filter2d) that does this convolution for you.
You need to provide your source and destination images, along with the custom kernel (as a `Mat`), and a few more arguments. See [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/filter_2d/filter_2d.html) if it still bothers you.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the previous answer, since you are performing Gaussian blur, you can use the OpenCV `GaussianBlur` (Check [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=gaussianblur#gaussianblur)). Unlike `filter2D`, you can use the standard deviations as input parameter.